# Vue - Array dosen't update

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

On click, I want to push to array. It works if I manually refresh the Vue extension in the console of Google Chrome but otherwise not

```
            completeStep(index, key) {
                let currentSet = index + key

               if (this.exercise_completed[index].indexOf(currentSet) === -1) {
                    this.exercise_completed[index].push(currentSet)
                } else {
                    this.exercise_completed[index].splice(this.exercise_completed[index].indexOf(currentSet), 1)
                }             
            }
```

Comment: Check this out: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html This is almost certainly the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try to use `this.$forceUpdate();` when you make the change.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making a key and changing the key on changes in the array. See here:
https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render